# Why cheesecake needs hard base?

Tags: cheesecake

I love cheesecake. I am sure you loves it too. One thing I don't know that why cheesecake needs the hard base that too made up from biscuits? Can't we just put normal base?

Edit :

Hard Base : graham cracker crust 
Soft Base : Pastry Sponge

Comment: I suppose cheesecake doesn't *need* any kind of base, except that the base makes it easier to remove from the pan-- it would stick to the bottom otherwise.  I suppose you could line with parchment paper, but how you'd get it off the bottom of the cake without damaging the top or sides I'm not sure.  What are you calling a "normal base"?

Comment: Isn't this as baseless an assumption as some cheesecake recipes?

Comment: What is a "normal base"? Do you mean the crust?

Comment: I have eaten cheesecales on sponge bases and pastry bases.  I've seen recipes for the latter.  But they're rare.

Comment: @Catija I assumed that to mean pastry

Comment: @ChrisH We can't really assume, though. We need to know else answers may be wrong.

Comment: @Catija agreed, hence my quick comment rather than tracking down recipes and writing an answer

Comment: @senschen Normal base as in the base that we generally use in Cakes.

Comment: @Catija Crust is what the hard base is. Normal base is simple Sponge base

Comment: @ChrisH You assumed right

Comment: You need to clarify that. As far as I'm concerned, graham cracker crust is "standard". You are also contradicting yourself... pastry crust is not sponge.

Comment: @Catija -  I am sorry my knowledge in baking field is very limited. So I just want to why we need that Graham Cracker Crust.

Comment: "Pastry sponge" doesn't make sense, though sponge cake would be part of a pastry chef's job. Pastry is what (most) pie crusts are made of. Sponge is a light form of cake.

Comment: Cakes don't generally have a base...?  You can use them as a base, but a cake (sheet cake, layer cake, whatever) doesn't generally have a base.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A cheesecake doesn't need a hard base, or any base at all. The cheese part of cheesecake is sticky and will stick to a pan, although there's ways to get around that. A base (whether spongy or hard) also gives a texture and flavor contrast which many people find works well for them.

It's just tradition really, you can do what you want with it, I've seen cheesecakes baked in individual ramekins with no base, it's really up to you.

Comment: So the main reason why we need base it because it wont stick to vessel? Doesn't it give support to the layer?

Comment: The base makes serving it in tidy slices simpler, so in that sense it does support the main part. But while slicing a cheesecake is traditional it's not compulsory. (@TheDictator)

Answer (score 3):

Cheesecake doesn't need to have a hard base. A traditional New York style cheesecake (i.e. Junior's) has a spongecake base.